# Laravel consumindo API e transformando objeto para array

Tags: php, laravel, api, framework

Seguinte estou fazendo um requisição do tipo `get` e está me retornando um `objeto` e gostaria que isto fosse um array , 
**já tentei utilizar**

```
$dados= Array.of($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

mas da erro!
**erro**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '('
```

**MEUS CÓDIGOS ->**

**web.api**

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;


Route::get('/', function () {


$client = new Client([
    // Base URI is used with relative requests
    'base_uri' => 'https://teste.herokuapp.com',
    // You can set any number of default request options.
    'timeout'  => 2.0,
]);
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'api/login');
    $dados= $response->getBody()->getContents();

    dd($dados);

   return view('posts.index', compact('dados'));
});
```

**dd($dados)**

```
"{"contas":[{"id":7,"email":"Ivan@mail.com","senha":"4154512"},{"id":1,"email":"lucas@mail.com.br.br.br","senha":"lucas123"},{"id":14,"email":"sehloiro@maill.com "
```

Comment: Já tentou isso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array ?

Answer (score -2):

Tente assim

```
$dados= json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents())->contas;
```